# Changing value in one list changes it in a seperate one

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to change a value in array normMap to another, but doing so also changes a value in array fireMap.

```
public int boardX = Board.boardX;
public int boardY = Board.boardY;
public int tileSizeX = Board.tileSizeX;
public int tileSizeY = Board.tileSizeY;
public int curr_dimension = Board.current_dimension;

public BufferedImage[] grassImage = {Board.norm.grassImage, Board.fire.grassImage};
public BufferedImage[] waterImage = {Board.norm.waterImage, Board.fire.waterImage};
public BufferedImage[] pathVImage = {Board.norm.pathVImage, Board.fire.pathVImage};
public BufferedImage[] pathHImage = {Board.norm.pathHImage, Board.fire.pathHImage};
public BufferedImage[] treeImage =  {Board.norm.treeImage, Board.fire.treeImage};

// y/x/tile type
public List<List<Integer>> normMap = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
public List<List<Integer>> fireMap = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
{
    int y = (int) Math.ceil((arg0.getY() + boardY * tileSizeY) / 32);
    int x = (int) Math.ceil((arg0.getX() + boardX * tileSizeX) / 32);
    switch(curr_dimension)
    {
    case(0): normMap.get(y).set(x, 0); break;
    case(1): fireMap.get(y).set(x, 0); break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) 
{
    switch(arg0.getKeyCode())
    {
    case(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER): writeFile(); break;
    case(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE): GameStateManager.setState(GameStateManager.MENU_STATE); break;
    case(KeyEvent.VK_UP): boardY--; break;
    case(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN): boardY++; break;
    case(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT): boardX--; break;
    case(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT): boardX++; break;
    case(KeyEvent.VK_1): curr_dimension = 0; break;
    case(KeyEvent.VK_2): curr_dimension = 1; break;
    }

}

public String getPrefix(int dimension)
{
    switch(dimension)
    {
    case(0): return "norm";
    case(1): return "fire";
    default: 
        System.out.println("Incorrect dimension, " 
    + dimension + ". Find the map in maps/custom/unidentified."); 
        return "unidentified";
    }
}

public void writeFile()
{
    List<List<Integer>> map;

    switch(curr_dimension)
    {
    case(0): map = normMap; break;
    case(1): map = fireMap; break;
    default: map = normMap; break;
    }
    PrintWriter writer;
    try 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            writer = new PrintWriter("/maps/custom/" + getPrefix(i) + "map1.txt", "UTF-8");
            for(List<Integer> list : map)
            {
                for(int integer : list)
                {
                    writer.print(integer + " ");
                }
                writer.println("");
            }
            writer.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void init() 
{
    Main.panel.addKeyListener(this);
    Main.panel.addMouseListener(this);

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        List<Integer> map1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            map1.add(9);
        }
        normMap.add(map1);
        fireMap.add(map1);
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    switch(curr_dimension)
    {
    case(0): drawTiles(g, normMap); break;
    case(1): drawTiles(g, fireMap); break;
    }

}

public void drawTiles(Graphics g, List<List<Integer>> map)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < map.size(); y++)
    {
        List<Integer> mapY = map.get(y);
        for(int x = 0; x < mapY.size(); x++)
        {
            if(mapY.get(x) == 0) g.drawImage(grassImage[curr_dimension], (x - boardX) * tileSizeX, (y - boardY) * tileSizeY, null);
            else if(mapY.get(x) == 1) g.drawImage(waterImage[curr_dimension], (x - boardX) * tileSizeX, (y - boardY) * tileSizeY, null);
            else if(mapY.get(x) == 2) g.drawImage(pathVImage[curr_dimension], (x - boardX) * tileSizeX, (y - boardY) * tileSizeY, null);
            else if(mapY.get(x) == 4) g.drawImage(pathHImage[curr_dimension], (x - boardX) * tileSizeX, (y - boardY) * tileSizeY, null);
            else if(mapY.get(x) == 3) g.drawImage(treeImage[curr_dimension], (x - boardX) * tileSizeX, (y - boardY) * tileSizeY - tileSizeY, null);
            else if(mapY.get(x) == 9) g.drawRect((x - boardX) * tileSizeX, (y - boardY) * tileSizeY, tileSizeX, tileSizeY);
            else if(mapY.get(x) == Board.PLAYER) GameState.player.draw(g, x, y, boardX, boardY, tileSizeX, tileSizeY);

        }
    }
}}
```

Expected output is two different lists. However, printing out fireMap and normMap reveals the same result.

Unimportant pieces of code removed. Please tell me if I need to clarify on anything.

Comment: Kindly add the code snipped in which you are facing errors or problems. Do not straight away paste the whole code.

Comment: Where are you trying to print the list values?

Comment: @FallAndLearn I have removed all the pieces of code that did not have to do with the problem, should I whittle it down further?

Comment: @SamuelRobert So I could compare them to check if they truly were the same, or if it was just a drawing issue.

Comment: Apparently you're trying to add the same elements in both the list inside your init() method. How can you expect it to be different?

Comment: Because I'm individually changing them by the click of my mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the same object to NormMap and FireMap right here:

```
    normMap.add(map1);
    fireMap.add(map1);
```

even though the two maps are different the object inside the maps is the same. Because you have the same Objects in both maps normMap.get(y)  and fireMap.get(y) are the same as well  and if you do

```
normMap.get(y).set(x, 0);
```

you change the fireMap Object as well. So your problem is, that you have two different Maps but all the Objects inside the maps are the same.

In my Opinion the easiest way to solve your problem would be to add two different Objects to your Maps:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    List<Integer> map1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> map2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
    {
        map1.add(9);
        map2.add(9);
    }
    normMap.add(map1);
    fireMap.add(map2);
}
```

Edit: If your Lists have fit sizes (50 x 50) and you never change that Size, I recommend you to use a two dimensional Array instead

```
int fireMap[][] = new int[50][50];
```

(Also: In games the tile maps are normally 2-D arrays)